# Appium: how to fetch the URL in webview

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am working on a android project where i need to verify some data from website in a `WebView`. Is there any way to pull URL link from `WebView`? My `WebView` doesn't show the address bar, its hidden.

I have tried using

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            System.out.println(contextNames);
        }
        driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]); 
        driver.context("WEBVIEW");
        driver.getcurrentURL();
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code, it would make it easier to understand what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
WebView webView;
webView.getUrl();  // Shows the url which is currently loaded in webview
Log.d("URL", url); // To show the url which has loaded into the webview in LogCat.
```